# Why AzureDevOps private NPM repo is so slow with node 14 and 16?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, azure-devops

I upgraded NodeJs to 14 (the same for 16), using NVM on my MacOs, removed package-lock.json and node_modules directory, and ran `npm i -verbose`, the installation is so slow and it shows `(cache stale)` for each package, it takes 1 or 2 minutes per package to install. If I revert NodeJs back to 12 or 10, there is no issue.

The following is `.npmrc` content and I don't want to go HTTP:

```
registry=https://nintex.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<MyCompany>/npm/registry/ 
always-auth=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be caused by outdated local cache.

Run `npm cache clean --force` will clean out the local cache and your npm install should be fast again

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-cache